# I keep getting react native expo app crashed with these dependencies

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo, react-navigation

I keep getting crash with these dependencies:
`"dependencies": { "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6", "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12", "expo": "~48.0.15", "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.1", "expo-file-system": "~15.2.2", "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1", "expo-location": "~15.1.1", "expo-sqlite": "~11.1.1", "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4", "react": "18.2.0", "react-dom": "18.2.0", "react-native": "~0.71.7", "react-native-maps": "~1.3.2", "react-native-web": "0.18.10" },`
I tried updating the version change the ~ and ^ the result slight different the first attempt I got white screen the next one I got crashed then the app closed. is there any solution? I want this to run normally without crashed and white screen error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When you say it crashes, are you running this through npm start? What is the error? There should be an error when it crashes somewhere.